# Unpacking from Result<Box<Any>, Box<Error>> to float32 rust. How to do it?

Tags: testing, rust, mocking, rust-tokio, serde-json

```
struct ExchangeCurrencyRequestsMock {
  base: String,
  to: String,
  amount: f32,
}
use core::any::Any;
use task::api::Requests;
use std::error;
use serde_json::Value;
use serde_json::Map;

type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn error::Error>>;

impl Requests for ExchangeCurrencyRequestsMock {
    async fn call(&mut self) -> Result<Box<dyn Any>> {
        let data = r#"
            [
              "USD": {
                "USD": "1.0",
                "PLN": "3.96",
                "AUD": "1.52",
                "EUR": "0.92"
              },
              "PLN": {
                "PLN": "1.0"
                "USD": "0.25",
                "AUD": "0.38",
                "EUR": "0.23"
              }
            ]
        "#;
        let resp: Result<Box<serde_json::Value>> = Ok(serde_json::from_str(&data)?);
        match resp {
            Ok(value)  => {
              let obj: Map<String, Value> = value.as_object().unwrap().clone();
              let ratio: f32 = obj[&self.base.to_ascii_uppercase()][self.to.to_ascii_uppercase()].to_string().parse()?;

              return Ok(Box::new(ratio*self.amount))
            },
            Err(_) => {
              let b: Box<dyn error::Error> = "Request got bad".into();

              return Err(b)
            },
        };
    }
}

#[tokio::test]
async fn call() {
      let mut client = ExchangeCurrencyRequestsMock{
        base: "USD".to_string(),
        to: "AUD".to_string(),
        amount: 100.0,
      };
      let result: std::result::Result<Box<dyn Any>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> = client.call().await;
      assert_eq!(result, 152.0);

}
```

How to return f32 from client.call ? I should unwrap result to get Box, then * to Box, get Any and downcast it to float32  and assert it. That's how I did, then I deleted it, because It didn't work.

I unwrapped result to get Box, then * to Box, get Any and downcast it to float32  and assert it, yet It didn't work

Comment: After filling in the missing `Requests` trait definition and replacing `assert` with `result.unwrap`, it panicked on this `unwrap` - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d12b595a62a2898010a4e3ab8a5ffd5e. Are you sure this example reproduces the same error you're actually hitting in real code?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs for `Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast), `downcast` is implemented on `Box<dyn Any>`, and it returns a `Result<Box<T>, Box<dyn Any>>`.

So, all we have to do is:

```rust
*result.unwrap().downcast::<f32>().unwrap()
```

This unwraps the original `Results`, downcasts to `f32`, then unwraps again (because the `dyn Any` may not be of type `f32`), and then moves out of the returned `Box<f32>`.

However, this sounds like an XY problem due to weird code architecture, perhaps the `Requests` trait should be changed to make it easier to use?

Comment: I did this way earlier, it didn't cast to float32.

Comment: @Shibbaz Then your code was incorrect or the box didn't contain an `f32` because [it definitely works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=826d3e6b231a8b11980e1ad38cf55c02). You should show us how you were attempting to downcast.

Comment: let value: f32 = *result.unwrap().downcast::<f32>().unwrap(); I did this way earlier as well. 

It seems like the problem is located here
async fn call(&mut self) -> Result<Box<dyn Any>>

it returns Result of Boxed values, The solution should work, maybe something with match?

Comment: @Shibbaz It seems far more likely that there isn't an `f32` in the box, but some other type instead. You should post a _complete_ code same that _we can compile and run ourselves_ demonstrating that the downcast doesn't work. It could also be that the function is returning `Err`. The first `unwrap()` would fail in that case; you might be confused and thinking it's the second `unwrap()` failing.

Comment: That's weird, compiler doesn't shout error in call func. It would notify that there is mismatch between types.

Comment: Done, It was in call func, I solved it. It was better to use json macro rather than serde json from_str.